# How to create a String for loop with String character increment?

Tags: java

I created a for loop in java with string variabe.
I want to add a character to the variable until that variable is equal to a set of characters.
I created that for loop. No errors was shown in console. But also no output "(
Where did I wrong?

```
for (String s = "*"; s == "* * * *"; s += " *") {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: [Don't use `==` to compare strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

Comment: @jsheeran That is one problem, but even changing to `equals()` won't entirely solve the issue.

Comment: The condition in the `for` loop is _not_ about "stopping once true" but rather "iterating while true".

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a very creative solution to a common beginner coding problem. However, it has two problems:

1. `==` doesn't work to compare strings. Instead, you need to use the `equals()` method: `s.equals("* * * *")`.
2. Even after fixing #1, the bigger problem is that the condition will never be true. The condition must be true to execute the code inside the loop. Since `s.equals("* * * *")` returns false the first time, the loop never executes.

You can try to fix this by making a different condition using a string. Alternatively, find a different way by using an `int` counter in the for loop.